# C# Clear/Reset Listbox populated with Datasource

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource, reset

I have some methods that lists a variety of details in multiple Listboxes that can be added to a client, e.g. different crimes. The method below selects all the crimes from the CriminalRecord table where the ClientId =  *selected client's id*  and then populates the `listCriminalRecord` listbox with this data.

```
private void PopulateCriminalRecord()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM CriminalRecord " +
            "a INNER JOIN ClientCriminalRecord b ON a.Id = b.CriminalRecordId " +
            "WHERE b.ClientId = @ClientId ORDER BY Crime ASC";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientId", newId);
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dTable);
        listCriminalRecord.DisplayMember = "Crime";
        listCriminalRecord.ValueMember = "Id";
        listCriminalRecord.DataSource = dTable;
    }
}
```

When the user is finished with entering the client's details, they will click a button, be prompted with a message etc etc.

```
private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you've finished & filled in all of the Client's details?", "Save and exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        DisableStep2();
        EnableStep1();
    }
}
```

The `EnableStep1();` method just enables and clears some textboxes and the `DisableStep2();` method does the same but disables some textboxes. After this, I want all of the listboxes to be reset/cleared. I've tried `listCriminalRecord.Items.Clear()` but it expresses an error. I'm unsure on how to do this.
Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
listCriminalRecord.DataSource = null;

Comment: Received a `Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` error so I don't think that works

Comment: Ok. Then try this listCriminalRecord.DataSource = null;

Comment: It worked! Thank you Dmitry (answer the question so I can give you a tick)